# web font script in html?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm using this script in the website Html to use these fonts , but it's a little slow and make the whole website load slowly, is there another way ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('\x3Cscript src="' + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//webfonts.creativecloud.com/ubuntu:n5,n3:all;open-sans:n3,n4,n7,n8:all;amatic-sc:n4,n7:all.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
```

Comment: How many fonts are you including? Do you actually need them all?

Comment: That script is in turn generating some base64 encode fonts, 8 fonts in total, 0.81MB in total, that is huge request, do you really need 8 custom fonts?

Comment: ummmm, no I'm using "open-sans, sans-serif, amatic-sc" in the css !
Can I implement them with out js ?

Comment: Why do you have a `script` element that just adds a `script` element, instead of having just `<script src="//..."></script>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fonts aren't going to change you can put them on the server locally and then the requests don't have to go to two places. Also you can put the script at the bottom of the page to load last so the content will show up first, though that will make it look strange because the fonts will change after the content loaded.

Comment: Sending requests to two places is actually a good thing - it helps download content in parallel.

Comment: You have a point. I stand corrected. In that case you can have it load slow, load weird, find a different place to host the fonts, or use less fonts. That's about all I can think of.